# Set default GCC to Fink-installed GCC 4.5?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, default, macos, fink

I've got GCC 4.2 that came with my installation of Mac OS X 10.6.4, plus GCC 4.5 installed via Fink. I wanted to use gcc_select to change the default compiler to GCC 4.5, but was told gcc_select does not exist.
Is there another way to set the default compiler? Or do I need to do so manually? If so, how?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used MacPorts to install my GCC 4.4, and also told MacPorts to download gcc_select:

```
sudo port install gcc_select
```

then I typed

```
gcc_select -l
```

to list the available versions. Then

```
gcc_select mp-gcc44
```

to switch. I haven't used Fink but hopefully you can install gcc_select from there :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but gcc_select -l does not return fink's installed gcc